# TSQL Multiple selects for Stats

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What would be the best  appropriate way to run multiple select queries and have the data be outputted into the same xml value?

```
SELECT 
    count(empID) as totalOrders 
FROM 
    chandlerBrandLaunch 
WHERE 
    orderStatus = 'Complete'
FOR XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('results');

SELECT 
   count(empID) as totalPayments 
FROM 
   chandlerBrandLaunch 
WHERE 
   paymentStatus = 'Complete'
FOR XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('results');
```

My statement is getting different data counts as well as the WHERE clause varies.

I just want to be able to pull stats for multiple items and include it all in the one output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull both in a single select, if this helps:

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when empid is not null and orderStatus = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end as totalOrders,
    sum(case when empid is not null and paymentStatus = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end as totalPayments
FROM 
    chandlerBrandLaunch
```